# Is having a constant that's not 0 for a linear mapping automatically mean it's not linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

If you have a linear mapping $L(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (c, x_2, x_3)$ where $c \neq 0$, is that automatically not linear? (Doesn't follow the linearity property)?

It just saves time on proofs if I know that it's not linear I can find a counter example rather than going through the process of proving $L(b \vec{x} + c \vec{y}) = bL(\vec{x}) + cL(\vec{y})$.

What I found was that, as long as the elements inside $( , … ,)$ did not have any constants that isn't 0, and only had linear equations (something like $x_1 + x_2$), it is always linear? Is that right to assume?
Sorry if this is a dumb question haha.

Comment: It's a linear transformation as long as each component of the image is a linear combination of $x_1,x_2,x_3$, that is, of the form $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3$. The only admissible constant is $0$ for $a_i=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since a linear transformation maps $0$ to $0$. Hence, for such $L$ to be linear, we must have $L(0, 0, 0)=(0, 0, 0)$. But $L(0, 0, 0)=(c, 0, 0)$, so $c=0$.